# Access methods from the view in the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a simple WPF program that reads from the clipboard. The program will have a notification icon with a context menu. And now for my question.

How can I call the methods CloseCBViewer(), InitCBViewer() from MainWindow from NotifyIconViewModel, so I can use them in ExitCommand to disconnect from clipboard and add a disconnect and connect options in a context menu.

For the system tray icons I'm using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon

NotifyIconViewModel.cs

```
 public class NotifyIconViewModel
 {
    public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
           get
           {
               return new DelegateCommand
               {
                   CommandAction = () =>
                   {
                       Application.Current.Shutdown();
                   }
               };
            }
         }
     }

    public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public Action CommandAction { get; set; }
    public Func<bool> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        CommandAction();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc == null || CanExecuteFunc();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public void InitCBViewer()
    {
        WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        hWndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(wih.Handle);
        // start processing window messages
        hWndSource.AddHook(this.WinProc);
        // set this window as a viewer
        hWndNextViewer = Win32.SetClipboardViewer(hWndSource.Handle);
    }  
enter code here
    public void CloseCBViewer()
    {
        // remove this window from the clipboard viewer chain
        Win32.ChangeClipboardChain(hWndSource.Handle, hWndNextViewer);

        hWndNextViewer = IntPtr.Zero;
        hWndSource.RemoveHook(this.WinProc);
    }
}
```

ClipboardResources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClipboardTextChecker">
    enter code here
    <ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Show" Command="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Hide" Command="{Binding HideWindowCommand}" />
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>

    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"
                    ToolTipText="Double-click for show checker, right-click for menu"
                    DoubleClickCommand="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}"
                    ContextMenu="{StaticResource SysTrayMenu}">

        <tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <local:NotifyIconViewModel/>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ClipboardTextChecker.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClipboardTextChecker"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
    <Application.Resources>
    enter code here
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ClipboardTextCheckerResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer, just want to let you know that this breaks the rules of MVVM:

```
  public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
           get
           {
               return new DelegateCommand
               {
                   CommandAction = () =>
                   {
                       Application.Current.Shutdown(); // <-- Don't do this
                   }
               };
            }
         }
     }
```

Your view-models are not supposed to know anything about the UI. By accessing the `Application` directly, you're breaking the rules. I will leave that up to you to discover later.

**To answer your question**

Your application is the `Application.Current`. Assuming it's the default name, you can cast it like this:

```
var myApp = (App)Application.Current;
```

In your `App.xaml.cs`, you can create a public method that does everything for you.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   public void CustomShutdown()
   {
       // Not 100% sure if this is how you get access to your main window. 
       var main = (MainWindow)Window.Current; 

       main.CloseCBViewer(); // This is your custom shutdown.

       Shutdown(); // This is equivalent to Application.Current.Shutdown()
   }
}
```

And in your original `ExitCommand`:

```
  public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
           get
           {
               return new DelegateCommand
               {
                   CommandAction = () =>
                   {
                       ((App)Application.Current).CustomShutdown(); 
                   }
               };
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Drive-by down-voting. Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

So, the MVVM way of doing this is to make sure that your view-model doesn't have links to your view. The appropriate way to do this might be to introduce an Exit event in your VM, then when you create your VM in the MainWindow you attach an handler to that event, which then detaches your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a decoupled publish-subscribe event methodology. There is one called the [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) that ships with Microsoft's Prism.

Note that recently Microsoft [open sourced Prism](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/03/19/prism-grows-up.aspx) - don't be concerned about that specifically, the [Event Aggregator pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) (and the EventAggregator library) is still the appropriate pattern to use here. This will enable you to define events, then separately and independantly register subscribers (listeners) for specific published events (the event aggregator acts as a broker and register for subscribers).